# How to move selected labels to unselected labels

Tags: flutter, text, colors, flutter-layout, navigationbar

My bottom navigation bar has icons and one is of different colour and it us in selected lable and others are in unselected label so how do i manage that.

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet?

Comment: No I don't know for that

Comment: you can check more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.